# Print forward sequencing followed by backward sequencing till the beginning?

Tags: java, recursion

I have an interesting problem to solve where I have given `start` and `end` integer values and I will need to print from `start` to `end` and then from `end` to `start` using recursion.

**for example -**

start = 2 and end = 5 then the method should print the following,

```
2,3,4,5,4,3,2
```

I can easily do the first part using the code,

```
public static void countUp(int start, int end) {    

    System.out.println(start);

    if(start< end){

        countUp(start+1, end);
    }
}
```

But, then the start value is increased within recursion and I don't have a way to find where to decrease. How can I improve my code mentioning only one method is allowed to use ? Currently, It's only printing

```
2,3,4,5 // I don't care about the commas
```

Comment: Okay, the thing is you are not allowed to use any iterative loops (for, while, do-while, for-each ) to solve this problem. Only recursion is allowed. There must be a solution :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes he can by just adding a println at the end of the if

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`countUp(start+1, end);` doesn't increase `start` - it computes `start+1` and passes the result to a new invocation of `countUp`, which will have *its own* value of `start`. Inside the current invocation, `start` still has the same value. After the recursive call has completed, control will return to the current invocation and will continue after the call. What happens if you simply print `start` at the end of your method?

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment, I solved it and provided as answer.

Answer (score 6):

try this,

```
public static void countUp(int start, int end) {    

 System.out.println(start);

  if(start< end){

     countUp(start+1, end);
     System.out.println(start); //backtracking

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I also ended up finally.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of the problem only with recursion is as following,

```
public static void countUp(int start, int end) {    

    System.out.println(start);

    if( start< end){

        countUp(start+1, end);
    }

    if( start != end){

        System.out.println(start);
    }
}
```